# how to display other data from table when mouse over

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

i need to fetch and display data using a table (shown on view below) from database when mouse-over and disappear when mouse is off.

here is the **model**

```
public function teacher_with_subject(){
    $this->db->select('*')
    ->from('teacher AS t')
    ->join('teacher_subject ts','t.computer_number=ts.computer_number', 'left')
    ->where('t.date_of_termination','0000-00-00')
    ->where('ts.date_of_end','0000-00-00');
    $query = $this->db->get();  return $query->result_array();
}
```

**controller**

```
$located=$this->select_model->teacher_with_subject();
```

**view**:-

```
if (count($located) > 0) {
    echo '<table>';

    foreach($located as $locate){
        echo "<tr><td>".$locate['computer_number']."</td><td>".$locate['name']."</td><"</td><td><img src=". base_url()."inc/images/confirm.png width='45' height='30' border='0' class='computer_number' data-id='".$locate['computer_number']."'/></td></tr>";
    }
    echo '</table>';
}
```

i want to display postal address and email address when mouse is over name

Comment: Why Java Tag ??

Comment: sorry it is JavaScript an not java

Answer (score 0):

Use the title attribute:

```
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>".$locate['computer_number']."</td>";
echo "<td title='".$locate["email"]."<br />".$locate["address"]."'>".$locate['name']."</td>";
echo "<td><img src=". base_url()."inc/images/confirm.png width='45' height='30' border='0' class='computer_number' data-id='".$locate['computer_number']."'/></td>";
echo "</tr>";
```